# Specifying :class of embedded ruby form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

If I would like to assign a class to my embedded ruby form, like so?:

```
<%= form_for(User.new) do |f|, :class => "form-horizontal"  %>
```

How could I go about doing it? I keep getting a syntax error.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at the form_for docs? I mean, clearly this doesn't make any sense from a ruby standpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

```
form_for(record, options = {}, &proc)
```

meaning:

```
<%= form_for(User.new, { :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f|  %>
```

Comment: hey @Axle888 - if that worked, you should mark the answer as accepted.  Happy to be of help